# C++ standard for defining public variable static const integer

Tags: c++, static, integer, constants

Where should I define a static const integer member variable in c++, in the header file where the class it is defined or in a cpp file?

It complies in both situation, If I let the definition inside the header file and If I move the definition in a cpp file, but which is the c++ standard?

Comment: If the item should be available to more than one source file it should be in the common header. If it's only for use by a single source file (or class) it should be in a single source file (or private header).

Comment: You must define it in one `.cpp` file. Defining in header and including it in multiple source files will trigger multiply defined symbol errors when linking

Comment: But if the variable is const, multiple symbols will be defined? And I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full quote from the C++ Standard about constant static members:

> If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or
>   enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify
>   a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is
>   an assignmentexpression is a constant expression (5.19). A static data
>   member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with
>   the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is
>   an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In both
>   these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. —end note
>   ] **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is
>   odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall
>   not contain an initializer**.

So if a const static member is not ODR-used then its definition outside the class is not required.

Note: by the way in this context it is unimportant whether a const static member is public or not.

Comment: And loosely speaking, "ODR-used" means used in a way that requires the existence of the actual object at runtime, rather than just knowing its value. For example taking the address ODR-uses it, as does passing it by reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your static member outside the class definition and provide the initailizer there.

For Standard method first do something like this

Declare static variable in header file

```
class Something
{
public:
    static const int s_nValue;
};
```

On top of cpp file initialize it like

```
const int Something::s_nValue = 1;
```

Comment: It would be better to provide the initialiser in the declaration inside the class; then it can be used in a constant expression.